# Workaround or Means to Pause/Resume MongoDB Realm Sync on Client Side?

Tags: mongodb, realm, mongodb-.net-driver

Has anyone found a means to effectively pause and then resume the sync process on client-side APIs for MongoDB Realm Sync setups?

I just want my app users to have the ability to choose when to sync the db, like when on wifi or their own network, etc... but so far I can't find a documented way to "pause|resume" the sync process programmatically.

I'm using Realm .net, but I'd be open to hearing about how anyone working with a Realm Sync client might have achieved the same effect?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Turns out there IS (of course) a mechanism to regulate sync for things like low-battery or mobile-data preferences.

https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/dotnet/examples/sync-changes-between-devices/#std-label-dotnet-sync-data

```
var session = realm.GetSession();
session.Stop();
//later...
session.Start();
```

Comment: Good answer, but let's also add **Don't use the .Stop() method to stop syncing for indefinite time periods or time ranges in months and years. The functionality is not designed or tested for these use cases, and you could encounter a range of issues when using it this way.**